# What is the difference (and the link) between the RADAR cross section (RCS) and the equivalent area of the target?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, microwave, radar

[Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/radar-cross-section#:%7E:text=The%20radar%20cross%20section%20(RCS,to%20that%20from%20the%20target)) it is written that:

> The radar cross section (RCS) σ of a target is the equivalent area seen
> by a radar. It is the fictitious area intercepting that amount of
> power which, when scattered equally in all directions, produces an
> echo at the radar equal to that from the target. Mathematically, it is
> written as:

$$\sigma = \lim_{R \to \infty} 4\pi R^2 \frac{|E_s|^2}{|E_i|^2}$$

where R is the distance between radar and target, Es is the scattered field strength at radar, and Ei is the incident field strength at target.

Then it says:

> The RCS of a target depends on the aspect angle, frequency, and polarization. It is not directly related to the physical area. When the object dimension is much greater than the wavelength, the RCS of a conducting plate with a physical area A observed at the normal direction can be approximated by the product of the effective gain of the plate and the physical area. The product is given by:

$$\sigma = G_e \cdot A$$

Can you explain me the difference between the meanings of RCS and effective area of the target? Why did people have to introduce such a new quantity? Wasn't effective area enough? And I can't see the suggested link (last equation) between the RCS and the effective area A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantics and context make it easy to confuse the different terms.

> Can you explain me the difference between the meanings of RCS and effective area of the target?

In most cases, they essentially are one in the same. However, from the two definitions you presented we see two main points of view:

$$\sigma=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}4{\pi}R^2\frac{|E_s|^2}{|E_i|^2}\tag{1}$$

$$\sigma=G_eA\tag{2}$$

1. This is the formal general definition from straight electromagnetics. Assumes a planar surface and exerts an infinite propagation range so we can apply planar wave assumptions.
2. This is the form resulting from antenna theory. It is of course related, but how we get here requires a few twists and turns.

In both cases they share the common definition:

"The echo area, or RCS, is *the area intercepting the amount of power that, when scattered isotropically, produces at the receiver a density that is equal to the density scaterred by the actual target*."

This is saying that we

1. Transmit some power density towards a target sufficiently far away to assume planar wave conditions.
2. The power density then impinges on the target of *unknown physical size*. The target then re-radiates the incident power **isotropically**. This is important because we assume that the target doesn't simply reflect all of the power incident on it in our direction. Only some fraction of that incident power will radiate back in our direction.
3. We measure the power density returned right before it hits our antenna.

For example, if

$$|E_s|^2 = \frac{|E_i|^2}{4{\pi}R^2}\tag{3}$$

Then this tell us that the received power is what we expect from the incident power at the target being re-radiated isotropically back to us. If this equality now changes to be greater than, the target is somehow focusing the return energy in our direction...just like an antenna!

So

1. \$\sigma = 1\$: The target at range \$R\$ re-radiates the incident power isotropically. This is the "nominal" target.
2. \$\sigma \lt 1\$: The target at range \$R\$ re-radiates only a fraction of the incident power in our direction. The target can have surfaces where the waves are radiated in different directions. The target could also have radar absorbent material, further reducing the RCS.
3. \$\sigma \gt 1\$: The target at range \$R\$ re-radiates the incident power after focusing it in our direction, like an antenna. This could for example be due to its shape (e. g. corner reflectors), its actual physical size, or both.

> Why did people have to introduce such a new quantity Wasn't effective area enough??

Again, this has to do with the context we're in. Between electromagnetics, antenna theory, and radar some terms mean the same thing or may be different based on the context. For example the term "effective area" can be a reference to RCS or the effective aperture of an antenna proper.

> And I can't see the suggested link (last equation) between the RCS and the effective area A.

This is where the antenna theory version of the expression comes in. We treat the target as an antenna (because it is). Following the same logic as above, if (3) is true then the target acted like an isotropic radiator which makes \$G_e=1\$ and so

$$\sigma = A$$

This should be intuitively satisfying: if we make the metal plate bigger, it should reflect more energy back. Therefore it would have a higher RCS.

Now, this is an approximation when we know a priori that we're dealing with a metal plate of area A. From (1) and (3), we don't have a reference of the true physical size of the target. However, if the true target size increases, in the case of a metal plate, and we take the measurements described, we expect it to focus more energy back towards our receiver.

This is what is expected in antenna theory: increasing the size of the radiator for a given frequency, we increase the antenna gain. When this radiates and we're normal to it, we expect to see more power and so we see the connection between (1) and (2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A last question: is the sentence  "The target then re-radiates the incident power isotropically" equivalent to the common statement "Informally, the RCS of an object is the cross-sectional area of a perfectly reflecting sphere that would produce the same strength reflection as would the object in question. "? Does Isotropic means a spherical object?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo I wouldn't use the term "sphere" as that is not quite correct. The RCS is a fictional area that does not assume a particular shape.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as the effective area. The given formula is written with the ratio of the squares of field strengths i.e. the ratio of power densities. The power densities are compared at the target generated by the radar and at the radar reflected back by the target. The distance should be considered to be so long that the arriving wave can be seen as a plane wave at both ends. That's the "R approaches infinity".

Plane wave assumption is needed to keep the mouths of rigorous mathematicians closed when the cross section is presented as a function of wavelength and direction angles in a spherical coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Some things reflect radar much better than others. For example, a stealth aircraft is designed not to reflect radar back towards the radar receiver and so it looks tiny. It has been claimed that the [F117 presents a radar cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-117_Nighthawk#Stealth) section approximating a bird. Whereas something optimized to reflect radar, such as a 1 metre cube consisting of corner reflectors will look the size of a 747 on radar

Comment: This obviously depends on wavelength - if the dimension of the reflector is electrically small then it's RCS is less.

Comment: @DDuck True, but modern radars are typically less than 4cm wavelength. The F117 shot down over Yugoslavia was detected because the Serbs had "old fashioned" long wavelength radars for which the stealth was not optimized